# Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open

Tags: php, ubuntu, magento, mcrypt

I'm using magento, when I load the page I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /Users/my-pathlib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63
```

I'm using php7.1 and have installed mcrypt:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.1-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However when I reload the page I get the same error?

What could I be doing wrong here?

-- EDIT

When I run php -i I see:

```
mcrypt

mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
Version => 2.5.8
Api No => 20021217
Supported ciphers => cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes => cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35887/call-to-undefined-function-mcrypt-module-open-in-lib-varien-crypt-mcrypt-php-o

Comment: @MrHeelis Yes I saw that, and I'm already doing that....

Comment: run `php -i` in a console and check if mcrypt is enabled

Comment: @Tobias yes mcrypt support => enabled

Comment: The `php.ini` used in PHP CLI is not always the same as the one used by PHP under Apache. Write a quick script and place in DocumentRoot `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and run it in your browser to see where the php.ini file lives that is used in Apache. Then check the extension is enabled in that file

Comment: @RiggsFolly looks like this: `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini`

Comment: Ok, so does that ini file have the mcrypt extension enables?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the strange thing is that I see in my php.ini file: `Darwin MacBook-Pro.local`. I run my php app in a homestead box. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry not a MAC user so you have lost me know

Comment: How to solve this error `undefined function mcrypt_module_open()` in windows server, Or how to install mcrypt module in windows server? Where I have php 5.3 on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to your magento version not being compatible with your php version.